# Logstash cannot recognize environment variables in JDBC input

Tags: jdbc, logstash

According to logstash [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html) I can do this:

`$ export VAR=some_value`

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => ...
        jdbc_user => ...
        jdbc_validate_connection => ..
        jdbc_password => ...
        jdbc_driver_library => ..
        jdbc_driver_class => ...
        jdbc_paging_enabled => ...
        jdbc_page_size => ..
        statement => "SELECT * FROM table where column='{$VAR}'"
}
...
```

Well, that did not work. So I tried:

```
input {
        jdbc {
            jdbc_connection_string => ...
            jdbc_user => ...
            jdbc_validate_connection => ..
            jdbc_password => ...
            jdbc_driver_library => ..
            jdbc_driver_class => ...
            jdbc_paging_enabled => ...
            jdbc_page_size => ..
            parameters => {"var" => "${VAR}" }               
            statement => "SELECT * FROM table where column= :var"
    }
```

But, nothing happened. Just to be clear, when I use

`statement => "SELECT * FROM table where column= 'some_value' "`

Everything works fine. So, how can I make logstash recognize the environment variable?

Comment: How do you define your environment variables? If you echo them in the same terminal that you run logstash from, do you see their value?

Comment: yep. I am using exporting like "export VAR=value". And echo $VAR outputs "value".